# Failure trying to read String using Scanner.nextLine()

Tags: java

I am trying to read a String and output it to the terminal, as well as a few primitives, but it does not seem to work. The code is below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int i = scan.nextInt();
        double d = scan.nextDouble();
        String s = scan.nextLine();

        scan.close();
        
        System.out.println("String: " + s + "\n");
        System.out.println("Double: " + d);
        System.out.println("Int: " + i);

    }
}
```

I have tried to find other ways to parse the string in the Scanner class, but none of them seemed to work. What I except is for the String to be properly read and outputed to the terminal, along with the few other values.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you press `enter` (when you digit the number) you are inserting a `\n` character inside the buffer, so when you will call `nextLine()` you will read the `\n` (because nextLine reads the input until the `\n`) and you will not be able to write anything because the function returns when found the `\n`.
You can clean it calling `scanner.nextLine()` one more time

```
int i = scan.nextInt();
double d = scan.nextDouble();
// Remove \n from buffer
scan.nextLine();
String s = scan.nextLine();
```

Comment: Or to be safer we can call `scan.skip("\\R?")` to skip line separator, if it exists. This way we don't risk that additional `nextLine()` will consume potential data left in same line, like `2.34 foo bar` when after `nextDouble` which would read `2.34` the the `nextLine()` *should* read `" foo bar"`. This would be impossible with extra `nextLine` before `String s = scan.nextLine();`.